# Proof for Marshallian Demand function

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory, choice-theory

If you have a Marshallian demand function that is strictly convex, then it satisfies WARP.
How to prove this?

Comment: You mean strictly convex (Marshallian) demand, or strictly convex preferences?

Comment: former case. Strictly convex Marshallian demand.

Comment: Convex in which arguments? In prices? In income? In prices and income?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x(p,w)$ be the demand at prices $p$ and income $w$.

Let $x_0 = x(p_0,w)$ and $x_1 = x(p_1, w)$. Note that $p_0 x_0 = w = p_1 x_1$

Assume that WARP is violated, so $x_1 \ne x_0$,
$$
p_0 x_0 \ge p_0 x_1 \text{ and } p_1 x_0 \le p_1 x_1.
$$

Consider any $\alpha \in (0,1)$, define $p_\alpha = \alpha p_0 + (1-\alpha) p_1$ and consider $x_\alpha = x(p_\alpha, w)$ (which means that $p_\alpha x_\alpha = w$).

By convexity of the demand:
$$
p_\alpha(\alpha x_0 + (1-\alpha) x_1) > p_\alpha x_\alpha.
$$

1. if $p_\alpha x_0 \le p_\alpha x_1$ then we have:
   $$
   p_\alpha x_1 > p_\alpha x_\alpha.
   $$
   As such,
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   w = p_\alpha x_\alpha &< p_\alpha x_1,\\
   &= \alpha p_0 x_1 + (1-\alpha) p_1 x_1,\\
   &\le \alpha p_0 x_0 + (1-\alpha) w,\\
   &= \alpha w + (1-\alpha) w = w,
   \end{align*}
   $$
   a contradiction.
2. If $p_\alpha x_1 \le p_\alpha x_0$, then:
   $$
   p_\alpha x_0 > p_\alpha x_\alpha.
   $$
   In this case we have the contradiction:
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   w = p_\alpha x_\alpha &< p_\alpha x_0,\\
   &= \alpha p_0 x_0 + (1-\alpha) p_1 x_0,\\
   &\le \alpha w + (1-\alpha) p_1 x_1,\\
   &= \alpha w + (1-\alpha) w = w.
   \end{align*}
   $$